# Why pipeline does not work for the file command?

Tags: bash

I found that `which cp|file` prints as the `file` command, can someone explain why?

Of course I know the command `file $(which cp)` works.

Answer (score 5):

The `file` command doesn't accept input from `stdin`.  You'll need to do something like `which cp | xargs file`

Comment: Thanks, it works, but how to know whether a command accepts input from stdin or not

Comment: @tmpbin a general rule of thumb is that commands will accept data on stdin, but rarely will they accept arguments that way

Comment: When in doubt check the `man` page.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `file` expects to be able to `stat()` the target, to identify block devices, named FIFOs, symlinks and the rest.

If the target is a regular file (or if `-s` is used), then it expects to be able to `seek()` to perform tests at the offsets specified in the magic file.

Neither of these is possible with a plain `stdin` stream.